# How to read jmeter response data that comes as a CSV using the JSR223 PostProcessor and assign it to a JSON object

Tags: groovy, jmeter, post-processor

I have an HTTP request that reads a csv file stored in a server. The response for that request comes as

```
login_type,username,password
data,data,data
data,data,data
```

(The file contains more than 1000 rows)
Is there a way to read these individual data and pass on to three variables as i am required to pass these data rows on to the next request as
`{"login_type":"${login_type}","username":"${username}","password":"${password}"}`

Using JSR223 PostProcessor i was able to read the response. The groovy script is below.

```
def res = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
log.info(res)
```

how can i parse these values into a json object and assign the values to the next request?

Comment: If you need to do it in Javascript, see: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-file-and-vice-versa-in-javascript/

Comment: @PierreFrançois I'm guessing this could be done using the JSR223 PostProcessor?

Comment: I don't know. For answering your question in an efficient way, we would need you to [create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be:

1. Executing the request which retrieves this file somewhere in [setUp Thread group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter)
2. Save it into a CSV file using [Save responses to a file listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file)
3. In the main Thread Group use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to read the values

Comment: The script is running on the aws so saving a csv and accessing it locally cannot be done. It is why I'm looking for an alternative way.